# Uncaught servlet exception in faces-config.xml when added exception-handler-factory

Tags: java, jsf-2, exception, websphere

When I was doing some experiment on JSF Exception Handling, I hit following error. Basically I don't really understand what this error trying to tell? Hope you guys can help me to decode the message.

```
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:153)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1078)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4173)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1006)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$1.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:253)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterHttp(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at org.huahsin.security.PfmInitFilter.doFilter(PfmInitFilter.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1036)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.huahsin.exception.JsfExceptionHandlerFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:281)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:203)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.<init>(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:238)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:203)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:320)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.huahsin.exception.JsfExceptionHandlerFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:268)
    ... 64 more

[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[ERROR   ] Error Page Exception:
```

This is what I configure in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<factory>
  <exception-handler-factory>
    org.huahsin.exception.JsfExceptionHandlerFactory
  </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

This is the `JsfExceptionHandlerFactory.java`:

```
public class JsfExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory factory;

    public JsfExceptionHandlerFactory(JsfExceptionHandlerFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory#getExceptionHandler()
     */
    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        ExceptionHandler result = new JsfExceptionHandler(factory.getExceptionHandler());
        return result;
    }

}
```

This is the `JsfExceptionHandler.java`:

```
public class JsfExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

    private ExceptionHandler handler;

    public JsfExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return this.handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {

        System.out.println("handle");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your constructor shouldn't it be public JsfExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

Comment: I have verify that JsfExceptionHandlerFactory is public.

Comment: No I mean the argument of the constructor, it should be ExceptionHandlerFactory not JsfExceptionHandlerFactory

Comment: Refer to [FactoryFinder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/FactoryFinder.html) for more info.

Comment: @Ravi Thank you so much on your effort. I have the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ravi, I have the problem solved in `JsfExceptionHandlerFactory` class by replacing the constructor argument with `ExceptionHandlerFactory`. Below is the updated code.

```
public class JsfExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory factory;

    public JsfExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory#getExceptionHandler()
     */
    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        ExceptionHandler result = new JsfExceptionHandler(factory.getExceptionHandler());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post this answer , Instead ask @Ravi to do so and accept his answer...